# This string comparison isn't working

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, compare, string-comparison

**So when I enter the month that I would like to use, such as December, and I put 722 as the hours, the program says, "The amount of hours you entered cannot exceed the amount of hours within the month 720". Is there a way to fix? I don't want to make if statements for each month, I feel there is an easier way. This is also my first college program**

```
int userPackage, userHours; //Declaring integer variables
double savings, savings2, total; //Declaring double value
string userMonth;
cout<<"\tHello.\nEnter the number of the package you have\n1) Package A\n2) Package B\n3) Package C\n"; //Prompts the user for their package in a menu like fashion
cin>>userPackage; //gets package
if(userPackage > 3 || userPackage < 1) //Error output for numbers that don't match packages
{
    cout<<"Error, invalid choice";
    return 0;
}

cout<<"Enter the number of hours you have been online."; //Propmts the user for the number of hours they've been online
cin>>userHours; //gets hours
cout<<"Enter the month (by name): ";
cin>>userMonth;
cout<<"\n";
if(userMonth == "January","March","May","July","August","October","December")
{
    if (userHours > 744)
    {
        cout<<"The amount of hours you entered cannot exceed the amount of hours within the month 744";
        return 0;
    }
}
if(userMonth == "April", "June", "September", "November");
{
    if(userHours > 720)
    {
        cout<<"The amount of hours you entered cannot exceed the amount of hours within the month 720";
        return 0;
    }
}
if(userMonth == "February");
{
    if (userHours > 672)
    {
        cout<<"The amount of hours you entered cannot exceed the amount of hours within the month 672";
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

Comment: `userMonth == "January","March","May","July","August","October","December"` This is not how you compare a string to multiple possibilities. You could store these strings in a static const array or set, and find if the string is within it.

Comment: `if(userMonth == "April", "June", "September", "November");`  I bet you have never seen an `if` statement like this printed in any book, tutorial, web site, etc.  that claims to be teaching C++.  So how did you come up with this?

Answer (score 1):

> `if(userMonth == "January","March","May","July","August","October","December")`

This does not do what you think it does (i.e., it **does not** compare `userMonth` to each of the strings. The statement you probably intended to write (it assumes you also want to use `else if` even though your code doesn't):

```
if (userMonth == "January" ||
    userMonth == "March" ||
    userMonth == "July" ||
    userMonth == "August" ||
    userMonth == "October" ||
    userMonth == "December")
{
    ...
}
else if (userMonth == "April" ||
    userMonth == "June" ||
    userMonth == "September" ||
    userMonth == "November")
{
}
else if (userMonth == "February")
{
}
```

**Note:** These are also case-sensitive comparisons (i.e., "january" is not equivalent to "January" or any other difference in case) and it may be better to convert everything to all lower or all upper casing.

> `if(userMonth == "April", "June", "September", "November");`
>   `// problematic trailing semi-colon                       ^`

This ends the `if` statement and the next block is executed unconditionally. Therefore, when `722` is entered it is ***always*** greater than `720` and you get the message you're seeing.

You have this same error in the `if` logic for "February" as well.

Comment: Your wording implies that `if(userMonth == "January","March", <etc>` is equivalent to `if (userMonth == "January" || userMonth == "March" || <etc>` which it is not.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried looking up a solution online, but didn't really know how to word my question. I'm still learning all of the terms. But yes, it worked and I was able to continue coding the program. Thank you very much!